# Blocking scheduler(apscheduler) cannot get the job list before starting

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I am unable to get the job list before I start blockingscheduler, I already have a job with id as

```
background_event_publisher
```

Now when I try to add -

```
jobstores = {
        'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=os.environ.get("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI", None))
    }
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(
        daemon=True, jobstores=jobstores, timezone=pytz.utc)
scheduler.get_jobs()
```

Gives

```
[]
```

Then

```
scheduler.add_job(fun, 'cron', hour='09', minute='30',
                                   id='background_event_publisher' , misfire_grace_time=3600)
scheduler.start()
```

Gives Error

```
apscheduler.jobstores.base.ConflictingIdError: 'Job identifier (background_event_publisher) conflicts with an existing job
```

Can't understand why are not getting anything in get_jobs() while it still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the scheduler has started, it only sees jobs tentatively added to it. It cannot access the job store because the job store is only initialized during scheduler initialization. If you need to just retrieve such information without actually running the scheduled jobs, you should start the scheduler in paused state (`scheduler.start(paused=True)`).

Comment: Then I think of checking through DB first if the job is present and then add the job if not present.

Comment: Should we report this issue in apscheduler?